# Trying to understand static variables. Why does 6 get printed in the 2nd to last print statement?

Tags: java, static

My understanding of a static field is that its last assignment is what that field's value will be wherever it is found in the class.  However, my understanding clearly isn't solid because I expected the 2nd to last print statement to print 30, not 6.  Please help me understand why it printed 6.

```
public class Whatever 
{
static int x = 2;
static int z;

public Whatever()
{
    z = x*3;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Whatever foo = new Whatever();

    System.out.println(foo.z); //prints 6

    Whatever.x = 10;

    System.out.println(foo.x); // prints 10
    System.out.println(foo.z); // prints 6 WHY?!?!

    Whatever bar = new Whatever();

    System.out.println(bar.z); // prints 30 as expected
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this, you need to know what `static` means. In Java, `static` variables are at the Class level. Another way to think about it is, all instances of that class see the same thing. So, in your example, no matter how many `Whatever` objects you create (even if you create NONE!) there is only one `x` and only one `z`.

So, let's walk through it...

```
// Executes z = x*3, setting z to 6 (as you expect)
Whatever foo = new Whatever();
System.out.println(foo.z); //prints 6

// Sets x to 10 (remember, x is static, you only have one of them!)
Whatever.x = 10;
System.out.println(foo.x); // prints 10

// Because since the last time you've created a Whatever, 
// nothing has changed z!
System.out.println(foo.z); // prints 6 WHY?!?!

// Now you've created a new Whatever, and z = x*3 gets executed
// in the constructor again
Whatever bar = new Whatever();


System.out.println(bar.z); // prints 30 as expected
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: OH! okay it just clicked! 
It's like if I typed:
`int x = 2;`
`int z = x*3;`
`x = 10;`
`System.out.println(z); //will print 6`
`z = x*3;`
`System.out.println(z); //will print 30`
Sorry I don't know how to put it all in one block of code. I'm new to stackoverflow.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Whatever.x = 10; // This only sets your "x" to 10.

System.out.println(foo.x); // prints 10
System.out.println(foo.z); // prints 6 - because x is 10, but z is still 6

Whatever bar = new Whatever(); // Now z = x*3 is called and z becomes 30.

System.out.println(bar.z);
```

Its just that the statement in your constructor `z=x*3` is not called always when you set some new value for `x`.

Comment: I clicked on the "up arrow" button since your answer helped my understanding as well, but unfortunately I read the other guy's answer first.
Thank you though!

Comment: No issues:) As long as you've your doubts cleared, doesn't matter whether its by me or anybody else!

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are called so because they are located **statically** in memory. When you instantiate your foo object, the constructor multiplies x by 3, and assigns the result to z.

When your main method begins,

x = 2 and z has not been instantiated.

When foo is instantiated,

x = 2 and z = x * 3. Since x is now 2, z = 2 *3 = 6

You then assign x to be 10.
Z is STILL 6 because z is not assigned until your bar object is called.

If you expect is to be 30 at that point in time, you would have to call z = x * 3 again.

**Changing the variable x will not automatically change the value of z**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

When a number of objects are created from the same class blueprint, they each have their own distinct copies of instance variables. (...)

Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects. This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables.

Comment: I had already read that whole page you linked me to before asking this question. Sorry, but your answer didn't help.

Comment: @KacyRaye well you never mentioned that you have read :) but i am glad that you had!

Comment: lol it's chill.  
Yeah I do my reasearch now because last time my account got banned for asking a "low-quality question" >.<

Answer (score 0):

Because z = x*3 is in the constructor method.
Constructor method is call when you write

```
Whatever foo = new Whatever();
```

so when u assign

```
Whatever.x = 10;
```

constructor method was not call again

Answer (score 0):

Lets c what happens line by line

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

```
Whatever foo = new Whatever(); // new is a operator to create an object. when the object is created it will try to call constructor . No constructor, it will fail to create the object. so Now the constructor is called. It calculates x*3 and puts the value to z.
System.out.println(foo.z); //prints 6. Here value of z is read printed. This is not method invocation. This is just reading value of z 
Whatever.x = 10; // This is an assignment statement. It just puts the value into x
System.out.println(foo.x); // prints 10 Just the values read 
System.out.println(foo.z); // prints 6 WHY?!?! // Here to value of z is read. If you see. now alteration of value is done on z. 
Whatever bar = new Whatever(); // this recalculates and puts the value on to z. That is why you are seeing change when you print z after this statement.
System.out.println(bar.z); // prints 30 as expected
System.out.println(foo.z); // Should also print 30 now. thats what static does
```

}

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Static variables will have only one instance across different instances.

Here

at first

Z was 2

When you call

```
public Whatever()
```

Z was changed to 6

after that you have changed X

but that had no impact on Z

so the value is 6

Thanks

Comment: I realize it had no impact on z...
I want to know WHY it had no impact on z.

Comment: We have given you the answer in first line - Static variables will have only one instance across different instances.